# Is there a way to select a just particular jobs to be queue in laravel?

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs, worker

Basically what i want to achieve is i only selected jobs in my app will be push to jobs to be able to execute it in a given time. what happen is when i change the **QUEUE_CONNECTION** to database in my env all process and event are pushing to the jobs table.

what i want is only selected jobs only to be included in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have in `queue.php`, something similar to this.

```
'connections' => [
    'db' => [
        ...
    ],
    'sqs' => [
        ...
    ],
],
```

You can trigger a job on a specific queue, with the method `onQueue()`.

```
dispatch((new DBJob())->onQueue('db'));

dispatch((new SQSJob())->onQueue('sqs'));
```